# Determine Variables of Importance in Naive Bayes Model

Tags: r, r-caret, naivebayes

I have developed the below Naive Bayes model which works fine:

```
set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(Overall_NB_VoI), replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)) 
NBtrainer <- Overall_NB_VoI[ind == 1,] 
NBtester <- Overall_NB_VoI[ind == 2,] 
NBmodel <- naive_bayes(FTR ~ ., data = NBtrainer, usekernel = T)
NBmodel
```

However, I want to determine which variables make the strongest contribution to this model. I have tried two techniques but both result in errors as per below:

```
library(caret)
varImp(NBmodel)
```

> Output: Error in UseMethod("varImp") :
> no applicable method for 'varImp' applied to an object of class "naive_bayes"

```
library(rminer)
Importance(NBmodel, data = NBtrainer)
```

> Output: Error in PRED(M, data[(1:L), ]) : could not find function "PRED"

Ideally, I would like to be able to create a graph of the different features

Any advise would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To use `varImp()` from `caret`, you need to train the model with caret. You can check the naive bayes models [available](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html), and for the package you are calling, it would be with the option `method="naivebayes"`.

If you want to just fit it without any crossvalidation, you can set trainControl to be `method="none"`, like below using an example dataset:

```
Grid = data.frame(usekernel=TRUE,laplace = 0,adjust=1)

mdl = train(Class ~ .,data=Sonar,method="naive_bayes",
trControl=trainControl(method="none"),
tuneGrid=Grid)
```

We can check the class, and also get out the variable importance:

```
class(mdl$finalModel)
[1] "naive_bayes"

varImp(mdl)
ROC curve variable importance

  only 20 most important variables shown (out of 60)

    Importance
V11     100.00
V12      86.30
V10      82.64
V49      82.12
V9       81.97
V48      73.16
V13      72.60
V51      70.68
V47      69.99
V52      66.62
V46      66.27
V45      61.13
V4       58.45
V36      58.43
V5       54.32
V1       53.82
V44      53.37
V21      51.01
V35      49.93
V8       49.78
```

For `rminer` its pretty much the same, you have to train a model using their [fit](https://rdrr.io/cran/rminer/man/fit.html) function, but when i checked, it seems they use naiveBayes from package e1071 to perform the fit, so not very sure if that's what you need.